# How to transform a Slick 2.1.0 MappedProjection so all its Columns are Options

Tags: scala, slick-2.0

Let's say I have a case class called `Blarg` consisting of properties with primitive types:

```
case class Blarg(
  x: String,
  y: Int
)
```

`Blarg`s are used in various classes, sometimes as `Option[Blarg]`, sometimes as `List[Blarg]`, and those classes are persisted. We also have a case class called `OptionalComplexThing` containing a property of type `Option[Blarg]`:

```
case class OptionalComplexThing(
  one: String,
  maybeInt: Option[Int],
  maybeBlarg: Option[Blarg],
  id: Option[Long] = None
)
```

The problem is how to create a default `MappedProjection` containing the appropriate sub-projection. Notice the `blarg` `MappedProjection` below. I want to be able to transform the `blarg` `MappedProjection` so all its `Column`s are `Option`s. I don't want to hard-code this example - there should be a generic way to do this using combinators.

```
class _OptionalComplexThings(tag: Tag) extends Table[OptionalComplexThing](tag, "optional_complex_thing") {
  def one      = column[String]("one")
  def maybeInt = column[Option[Int]]("maybe_int") // specifying O.Nullable makes no difference
  def id       = column[Option[Long]]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)

  // Blarg fields need to have their lifted types remapped according to MappedProjection usage.
  // Notice OptionalComplexThing's maybeBlarg property is an Option[Blarg].
  def x   = column[String]("x")  // want to map to column[Option[String]]("x")
  def y   = column[Int]("y")     // want to map to column[Option[String]]("y")

  def blarg = (x, y) <> (Blarg.tupled, Blarg.unapply)

  def * = (one, maybeInt, Option(blarg), id) <> (OptionalComplexThing.tupled, OptionalComplexThing.unapply)

  /* Error:(23, 46) No matching Shape found.
  Slick does not know how to map the given types.
  Possible causes: T in Table[T] does not match your * projection. Or you use an unsupported type in a Query (e.g. scala List).
    Required level: scala.slick.lifted.FlatShapeLevel
       Source type: (scala.slick.lifted.Column[String], scala.slick.lifted.Column[Option[Int]], Option[scala.slick.lifted.MappedProjection[Blarg,(String, Int)]], scala.slick.lifted.Column[Option[Long]])
     Unpacked type: (String, Option[Int], Option[Blarg], Option[Long])
       Packed type: Any
    def * = (one, maybeInt, Option(blarg), id) <> (OptionalComplexThing.tupled, OptionalComplexThing.unapply)
                                               ^ */
}
```

[Here is a a GitHub project](https://github.com/mslinn/slick_2.1.0_mappings/blob/optional/src/main/scala/OptionalComplexThings.scala) that demonstrates the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could write your custom versions of tupled/unapply methods:

```
case object Blarg {
  def fromOptions(maybeX: Option[String], maybeY: Option[Int]): Option[Blarg] = {
    (maybeX, maybeY) match {
      case (Some(x), Some(y)) => Some(Blarg(x, y))
      case _ => None
    }
  }

  def customTupled = (fromOptions _).tupled
  def customUnapply(arg: Option[Blarg]): Option[(Option[String], Option[Int])] = arg.map { blarg =>
    (Some(blarg.x), Some(blarg.y))
  }
}

class _OptionalComplexThings(tag: Tag) extends Table[OptionalComplexThing](tag, "optional_complex_thing") {
  def one      = column[String]("one")
  def maybeInt = column[Option[Int]]("maybe_int")
  def id       = column[Option[Long]]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def maybeX   = column[Option[String]]("x")
  def maybeY   = column[Option[Int]]("y")

  def blarg = (maybeX, maybeY) <> (Blarg.customTupled, Blarg.customUnapply)
  def * = (one, maybeInt, blarg, id) <> (OptionalComplexThing.tupled, OptionalComplexThing.unapply)
}
```

This might not be the shortest possible solution, but should work.

Comment: This is the hand-crafted approach that I would like to avoid. The problem with this approach is that someone must maintain it, and as projects move into the future, people leave and case class properties change. Instead, I would like to use combinators. How could something similar be achieved without hand-crafting Blarg.fromOptions and customUnapply?